# Cannot get CF migration table back in line

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I did some manual changes to the database (stupidly) to try and fix an issue I was having but now it has gotten my model and context out of synch.

I have tried removing the migration history table, deleting my migrations folder, then re-running

```
enable-migrations  
add-migration Initial 
Comment out the up() method
update-database
```

This recreates the migrationhistory table in theory with what my current model is, but when I run the code I still get

> The model backing the 'EmtDataContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database

What else can I try? I'm effectively in the situation where I am starting over, I want to create an initial migration reference that I can build future changes on top of. I think the problem is that the DB schema is now not the same as my model but I don't know how to find out what is different and I cant drop and recreate the DB as there is critical data in it.

How can I get my DB schema back in line with my context?

Update: I've gone through all of my model classes and compared to the current tables in the DB. They all match, so it looks like my schema is in line. I have removed anything to do with migrations and it runs fine. So this implies my model matches the DB. It seems to be when I try and set up migrations again by enabling migrations and running the initial blank create to set up the initial entry in the DB, it writes something invalid to that table. So I can run it without migrations set up but cannot seem to re-setup migrations again

Answer (score 1):

After you remove the old migration code and __MigrationHistory:

```
1) enable-migrations 
2) add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges --(same as commenting out Up() code
3) update-database
```

Net effect should be the same as you have done, so if you are still getting model mismatches, try adding another migration and examine the code for what EF is trying to update.

If nothing pops up there, it could be your initializer. Using `Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);` would get you past the error, but kind of like sweeping it under the carpet.

Other things to look at or try:

- Your connection string is going where you think.
- Multiple contexts? Inherited context? Show the code.
- You have the project with your context selected in package manager console

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to delete the database and all the migration scripts and then run `add-migration` and `update-database`. This will create a brand new schema.

If you have data in the existing database that you need then you have two options. One is to create a `seed` function. The other is to backup the existing database, restore it to a database with a different name and then write scripts or similar to restore the data on a table by table basis.